# How do you shim react-pdf with esbuild?

Tags: react-pdf, esbuild

If you bundle react-pdf for the browser using esbuild today you will run into errors that prompt you to build for platform=node because zlib and stream are not available in the browser environment.

I did find a [conversation](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1317) around how to [swap this](https://github.com/exogee-technology/vite-plugin-shim-react-pdf/blob/main/src/index.js#L36-L39) when using vite but I'm curious if others have created a shim for esbuild that offers something equivalent

```
process: "process/browser",
stream: "vite-compatible-readable-stream",
zlib: "browserify-zlib"
```

the version I'm using today: `@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.21"`

*edit*

It just so happens a node modules polyfill exists for esbuild and you should be able to configure this as a plugin

https://github.com/remorses/esbuild-plugins#readme

`npm i -D @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill`

and then w/ esbuild you can pass it in like so

https://esbuild.github.io/plugins/#using-plugins

More after I confirm this is working end to end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using esbuild v0.14.10 and 2 plugins

```
npm i -D @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
npm i -D @esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill
```

With a build configuration like this

```
const esbuild = require('esbuild')
const globalsPlugin = require('@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill')
const modulesPlugin = require('@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill')

const args = process.argv.slice(2)
const deploy = args.includes('--deploy')

const loader = {
  // Add loaders for images/fonts/etc, e.g. { '.svg': 'file' }
}

const plugins = [
  globalsPlugin.NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
      process: true,
      buffer: true,
      define: { 'process.env.NODE_ENV': deploy ? '"production"' : '"development"' },
  }),
  modulesPlugin.NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
]

let opts = {
  entryPoints: ['js/app.js'],
  bundle: true,
  target: 'es2017',
  outdir: '../priv/static/assets',
  logLevel: 'info',
  inject: ['./react-shim.js'],
  loader,
  plugins
}

if (deploy) {
  opts = {
    ...opts,
    minify: true
  }
}

const promise = esbuild.build(opts)
```